# Why does the medium affect the Coulomb's constant but not the gravitational constant?

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, coulombs-law, dielectric

### Why does the medium affect the Coulomb's constant but not the gravitational constant?

My friend said maybe the particles of the medium affect the electric field. But the net charge in the medium is 0 so shouldn't the net change in the electric field be 0?
And even if he's right shouldn't the particles in medium affect the gravitational constant, even if the change is small?

Answer (score 2):

A neutral object can be *induced* a non-zero charge when placed in an electric field. The charges or dipoles within that material will simply rearrange or rotate to aline slightly. An electric field will be generated, which will counteract the current field. Have a look at **dielectrics**.

The gravitational constant $G$ is... A constant. Just like the permeability $\epsilon_0$ within the Coulombs law. Or like $\pi$. The *gravitational field* might change at a point because of the additions from all other bodies, just like the electric field will.